# Cannot read a value inside form input type which stored in cookie

Tags: html, angular

How can i get the data 'ex: userid' automatically while adding account details inside form. here is my code.

```
  <input id="UserId" type="text" name="UserId" value="{{userid}}" ngModel class="validate" readonly>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?? You are anyway binding it. value will have userid

Comment: <input [(ngModel)]="username"> ngModel should be given something like this

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need do the 2-way-bind over the input so your form object reactive to the changes you do

```
<input id="UserId" type="text" name="UserId" [(ngModel)]="userid">
```

or.. if you only want get value you can do the 1-way-bind over the input, and your object will get the value

```
<input id="UserId" type="text" name="UserId" (ngModel)="userid">
```